# Create where clause with column name only known at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am looking for a solution for the above Entity Framework problem.

The basic concept of what I want to achieve is this:

```
string columnName = "whatever";
var data = context.MyObject.Where(x => x.columnName == value);
```

I have looked around and found a solution for Linq to handle this, but it does not work with LINQ to Entities.

```
var data = context.MyObject.Where(
    p => p.GetType().GetProperty(columnName)
                    .GetValue(p, null) as string == value);
```

This throws the exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I also want to avoid using SQL or SQL like commands.  Anyone done/seen anything similar?

Edit: Been working on this some more and have got to this point.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> DynamicWhere(string _property, IList<string> 

_compare)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = m_context.Set<TEntity>();

            var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
            var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, _property);
            MethodInfo method = typeof(IList<string>).GetMethod("Contains");
            var someValue = Expression.Constant(_compare, typeof(IList<string>));
            var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

            return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(containsMethodExp, parameterExp));
        }
```

Things look good until the MethodInfo line, which is returning null

Comment: EF cannot translate reflection method calls into SQL. Use Dynamic Linq or expression builder

Comment: Because `IList<string>` is an interface, you have to take the interface where Contains is defined. Thus, use `typeof(ICollection<string>)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to Entities takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. You can either specify this expression by a lambda expression or you could construct this expression at runtime.

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
      Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty("MyProperty")),
      Expression.Constant(value)), parameter);

var result = queryable.Where(expression);
```

**Edit:** These expression trees can get complicated and the code to write them can get hard to read. A good methodology how to retrieve them is to create a method that takes an expression tree and experiment with what the compiler creates for several lambda expressions.

Comment: this is looking good.  could it be modified to instead of doing equivalent of `.Where(x => x.blah == 'blah)` it does `.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.blah)`

Comment: @Thewads Yes, it can. You would basically have to resolve the Contains function on your own. If you are lucky enough, the collection implements the non-generic IList interface, otherwise the code gets a bit clumsy.

Comment: hmm alright.  this whole expression tree thing is new.  Any pointers on how to achieve the list.contains?

Comment: If you know that Contains is a public method, then you can just retrieve it as `typeof(ListType).GetMethod("Contains")` and then create a MethodCallExpression (via `Expression.Call`). Otherwise, you would have to review what generic interface based on ICollection<T> the collection class implements and grab the Contains method through this interface. The bad point of manually created expression trees is that you have to do a lot of resolving that is usually done by the compiler.

Comment: Added where I currently have got to in question if yo are able to have a little look at see if I am going in the right direction

Comment: Alternatively you can use `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>, T, bool>> contains = (collection, x) => collection.Contains(x)` however there is a lot of work to get the body out then using a `ExpressionVisitor` to replace the parameters.